# + 20000")syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is "

Tags: linux, ubuntu-14.04

what the error means actually..Whenever i do 
sudo apt-get install 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get remove or restart some packages in ubuntu14.04 i am getting this error that invalid arithmetic operator.

Answer (score 0):

It means that your text has an embedded CR right before a "+ 20000".